# Passing JSON Config into multiple instances of the same bundled React Application

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack

I have several instances of a [react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) carousel. Each of them requires a different set of config options.

Currently, I have the carousel component bundled up via webpack and then deployed to multiple locations. Unfortunately, this means that the bundle is slightly different in each case, as the config file changes the overall bundle! What's the right approach for this solution?

I feel like I can think of the following solutions:

1) Load the config file asynchronously. Seems like a lazy solution, because making an extra round trip is overkill.

2) Try to use [require.ensure](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) to split out the config file into it's own chunk.

What's the right approach for this solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To reply for point 1, I've managed to accomplish runtime loading of config this way:

```
import xhr from 'xhr'
class Config {

    load_external_config = (cb) => {
        xhr.get("config.json", {
            sync: true,
            timeout: 3000
        },(error, response, body)=>{
            if(response.statusCode==200) {
                try{
                    const conf = JSON.parse(body);
                    for(var i in conf) {
                        this[i] = conf[i];
                    }
                }catch(e){
                    /* Manage error */
                }
            } else {
                /* Manage error */
            }
        })
    }

}

export let config = new Config();
```

The class above has two basic functions, on the one hand it is a "singleton", so every time you import it in each file of your project, the istance remain the same and will not be duplicated. On the other hand, through a XHR package it loads (synchronously) an external json file and puts every config voice in its instance as a first level attribute. Later, you will be able to do this:

```
import { config } from './config'

config.load_external_config();
config.MY_VAR
```

For point 2 I would like to see some examples, and I will remain tuned to this post for someone more skilled than me.